# where can I buy a Lenovo X220 with ubuntu preinstalled?

Tags: lenovo

this link here: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/make/Lenovo states "Pre-installed only" for the X220 leading me to believe I can buy this model with Ubuntu preinstalled. I've been unable to find such an option at Lenovo's website.

Comment: It might be for Business Customers only.

Comment: I contacted Lenovo and they said they do not sell any systems without Windows 7. What is the link in my question referring to if Lenovo does not sell systems without Windows 7?

Comment: They won't sell any systems without Windows 7 to YOU (or me). Try being a large corporation with a larger budget and their answer may change.

Answer (score 2):

I looked around and there isn't a lot of info on that.  It does appear that [Canonical's collaboration with Lenovo](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Canonical-Will-Collaborate-With-Lenovo-199265.shtml) is very recent, with the press announcement dated May 9, 2011, so hopefully Lenovo systems with Ubuntu will start appearing soon.

That said, I did find one vendor that will preinstall Ubuntu on the X220 [HERE](http://www.emperorlinux.com/mfgr/lenovo/raven/?tab=details&id=658).

Answer (score 2):

*This may not help you but I say it anyway.*

I'm sitting in front of an [X220i **student model**](https://www.lapstars.de/product_info.php?cPath=228_911&products_id=7220&osCsid=f25d9ba49d8776b62b537477bf359fba) (this is german but it doesn't matter for the components) right now.

I live in Germany and Lenovo has a **special student programme** here. So **they sell Thinkpads** with special configurations and really low prices and **without operation system.**

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 and everything just worked out of the box. So I can really recommend this notebook.

I don't know where you live but if you have a friend who is student in Germany, you may want to visit him now ;) ... or the other way round. But pay attention on not making it look like smuggling :D

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Raven X220 family](http://www.emperorlinux.com/systems/small/raven/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Mitch This isn't a link as an answer. It is a link to products. With that said, explanation would be very useful.